# criar data.frame onde a saída do arquivo seja colocada em colunas

Tags: r

Ola!
Estou com probleminha em R.... Possuo um arquivo chamado `dados_dia` com diferentes variáveis meteorológicas: `Índice de claridade (I.Cla),`Velocidade do vento (speed), `Umidade relativa (hH)`e `Temperatura do ar (Tai)`. Preciso encontrar as datas em que uma série de combinações dessas variáveis ocorrem (144 combinações, para ser mais exato). Para isso tenho um script no qual uso um "`for`" para gerar essas combinações e para encontrar as datas. Como cada combinação resulta em quantidades de datas diferentes, não estou conseguindo escrever essas datas em um vetor ou em outro arquivo, apenas fazer um `print`.
segue o script:

```
          I.Cla <- c(0,0.3,0.6,0.9)
          speed <- c(0,2,4,8)
          Tair <- c(0,14,19,24,40)
          rH <-  c(0,70,80,90,100)
combinacao = NULL

    m=1

          for(i in 2:4){
            for(j in 2:4){
              for(l in 2:5){
                for(k in 2:5){

        ######################################################################
        ############# condições das variáveis ################################

         combinacao[m] <- paste('I.Cla > ',I.Cla[i-1],' e I.Cla <= ',I.Cla[i],
                          'speed > ', speed[j-1],' e speed <= ',speed[j],
                          'Tair > ',Tair[l-1],' e Tair <= ',Tair[l], 
                          'rH > ',rH[k-1],' e rH <= ',rH[k] )

        m=m+1

        #####################################################################
        ############# datas em que ocorrem cada condição das variáveis ######

        print(c(dados_dia$date[dados_dia$I.Cla > I.Cla[i-1] & 
                               dados_dia$I.Cla <= I.Cla[i] &
                               dados_dia$speed > speed[j-1] &
                               dados_dia$speed <= speed[j] & 
                               dados_dia$Tair > Tair[l-1] & 
                               dados_dia$Tair <= Tair[l] &
                               dados_dia$rH > rH[k-1] &
                               dados_dia$rH <= rH[k]] ) )

                             }
                       }
                  } 
             }
```

Eu preciso que as condições das variáveis (combinacao) sejam as colunas do meu `data.frame` e as datas geradas no print sejam dispostas nas colunas que condiz a mesma. OBS: Os resultados vão de zero a 20 datas.

Comment: Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Falta informação sobre o que é `dados_dia`. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/824/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%c3%adnimo-reproduz%c3%advel-em-r) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Comment: A pergunta continua não sendo reproduzível.

Comment: O problema é variável `dados_dia`. Sugiro utilizar o `dput`e postar aqui o resultado.

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui... Criei uma matriz com o nº de colunas correspondente ao tamanho do vetor `combinacao[m]` e a transformei em um `data.frame`.

O problema que eu tinha era introduzir os resultados dos comandos executados dentro do `print` dentro de cada coluna, pois tratava-se de números diferentes de resultados. A solução era simples......

Introduzir nas linhas do meu `data.frame` mais um `for` com o comprimento da saída do `print`. Assim, a quantidade diferente de resultados é depositada em cada coluna....

segue script:

```
tabelas <- matrix(nrow = 100 , ncol = length(combinacao) )
colnames(tabelas) <- combinacao

          tabelas <- data.frame(tabelas)
c=1

        for(i in 2:length(I.Cla)){
          for(j in 2:length(speed)){
            for(l in 2:length(Tair)){
              for(k in 2:length(rH)){ 

bla <- dados_dia$date[dados_dia$I.Cla > I.Cla[i-1] & 
       dados_dia$I.Cla <= I.Cla[i] &
       dados_dia$speed > speed[j-1] &
       dados_dia$speed <= speed[j] & 
       dados_dia$Tair > Tair[l-1] & 
       dados_dia$Tair <= Tair[l] &
       dados_dia$rH > rH[k-1] &
       dados_dia$rH <= rH[k] ] 

        for(m in 1:length(bla)){

 tabelas[m,c] <- as.character(bla[k])

        }

 c=c+1
                 }
                }
              }
           }
```